# No content types available

Tags: drupal

After installing drupal 7.34 I have a functioning site but I see no content types listed (under admin/structure/types).  I would expect to see some basic, core types listed here.  Also, visiting a path such as "node/add/page" brings me to a page having the message, "You have not created any content types yet".

The 'node_type' table is empty, which seems suspect.

Is this normal or did something go wrong with the installation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using user/1 (who should have all required permissions), or otherwise another user who has the required permissions. If these assumptions are not correct then first check the permissions for the userid you're using.

Maybe you're suffering an issue related to one of the menus, such as the navigation menu. To find that menu within "admin", go to Structure > Menus > Navigation, and then use "list links" of the Navigation menu.

Checkout [this support issue on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/1218606#comment-5453438), and which includes this suggestion:

> go to Structure, Menus, Navigation, click on list links, and recheck the boxes for all your content adding.

Another possibility could be that [the Add Content" link was removed from the Navigation menu](https://www.drupal.org/node/997444#comment-3823720), for which the solution is like so:

> re-enabled this item and the ability to add content is back.

Yet another variation of this: [Check the content types parent menu item in the navigation menu](https://www.drupal.org/node/2288453#comment-8892727), with solution like so:

> Are the content types still listed and enabled as child items?